# Continually update table based off async mongoDB query

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to write a webpage that pulls from a mongoDB and updates a table based on the values returned. Currently I am able to do query the mongoDB using motor and work on each message asynchronously. However I am only able to write once per load of the page. I am wondering if there is a way to setup tornado to pull from the mongoDB continously as long as the page is open? This is what i currently have working per page load but im unsure how to get this working dynamically updating based on when the mongoDB is updated.

```
import tornado.ioloop, tornado.web, motor

class LoadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        db = self.settings['db']
        self.write('''
        <<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>Coin Info</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <script type=text/javascript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <style>
                  div.table {border: 1px solid black; display: table; width: 500px;}
                  div.row {border: 1px solid black; display: table-row; }
                  div.cell {border: 1px solid black; display: table-cell; }
                  div.wrapper { float: left;width: 200px; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="header">
                            <div class="cell">Name</div>
                            <div class="cell">Item1</div>
                            <div class="cell">Item2</div>
                            <div class="cell">Item3</div>
                        </div>
        ''')
               db.posts.find().sort([('_id',-1)]).each(self._got_message)

    def _got_message(self, message,error):
        if error:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, error)
        elif message:
            self.write('<div class="row">')
            self.write('<div class="cell" data-name={0}>{0}</div>'.format(message['values']['name']))
            self.write('<div class="cell" data-item1={0}>{0}</div>'.format(message['item1']))
            self.write('<div class="cell" data-item2={0}>{0}</div>'.format(message['values']['item2']))
            self.write('<div class="cell" data-item3={0}>{0}</div>'.format(message['values']['item3']))
             self.write('</div>')
        else:
            self.write('</div></div></div></div></body>')
            self.finish()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.write('here')
        self.finish()

db = motor.MotorClient().current_db

application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/load/', LoadHandler),
        (r'/', MainHandler)
    ], db=db
)

print('Listening on http://localhost:5000')
application.listen(5000)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular HTTP connection is closed as soon as the server finishes sending the response. So, you can't send any data to the client after the connection gets closed.

To send real-time data updates to the client, you can use Websockets. Unlike a regular HTTP connection, a Websocket connection stays open for as long as you want and a server is free to send data to the client whenever it wants to.

Tornado's [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html) is pretty good to get started with Websockets. For some advanced stuff, there's a [demo](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/branch4.5/demos/websocket) of a chat app - feel free to play around with that.